# Why my solution return right result in console and wrong in Leetcode? Task 937. Reorder Data in Log Files

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Task https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-data-in-log-files/
One of my solution pass all leetcode tests and other is falling with an error:

**Accepted solution:**

```
var reorderLogFiles = (logs)=> {
    let head = []
    let tail = []
    logs.forEach((val, i) => {
    if (!isNaN(val.split(" ")[1])) tail.push(val)
    else head.push(val)
  })
  return head.sort((a, b) => {
    let aStr = a.replace(/\w* /, ''), bStr = b.replace(/\w* /, '')
    return aStr !== bStr ? aStr.localeCompare(bStr) : a.split(" ")[0].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[0])
  }).concat(tail)
}
```

**Not valid solution:**

```
var reorderLogFiles = (logs) => {
  return logs.sort((a, b)=>{
    let isDigit1 = !isNaN(a.split(" ")[1]), isDigit2 = !isNaN(b.split(" ")[1])
    if (!isDigit1 && !isDigit2) {
      let aStr = a.replace(/\w* /, ''), bStr = b.replace(/\w* /, '')
      return aStr !== bStr ? aStr.localeCompare(bStr) : a.split(" ")[0].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[0])
    }
    return isDigit1 ? (isDigit2 ? 0 : 1) : -1;
  })
}
```

test case

`["6p tzwmh ige mc", "ns 566543603829", "ubd cujg j d yf", "ha6 1 938 376 5", "3yx 97 666 56 5", "d 84 34353 2249", "0 tllgmf qp znc", "s 1088746413789", "ys0 splqqxoflgx", "uhb rfrwt qzx r", "u lrvmdt ykmox", "ah4 4209164350", "rap 7729 8 125", "4 nivgc qo z i", "apx 814023338 8"]`

My output in console for both solutions (similar with expected):

```
["ubd cujg j d yf", "u lrvmdt ykmox", "4 nivgc qo z i", "uhb rfrwt qzx r", "ys0 splqqxoflgx", "0 tllgmf qp znc", "6p tzwmh ige mc", "ns 566543603829", "ha6 1 938 376 5", "3yx 97 666 56 5", "d 84 34353 2249", "s 1088746413789", "ah4 4209164350", "rap 7729 8 125", "apx 814023338 8"]
```

leetcode output for second solution with this test case:

```
["ubd cujg j d yf","u lrvmdt ykmox","4 nivgc qo z i","uhb rfrwt qzx r","ys0 splqqxoflgx","0 tllgmf qp znc","6p tzwmh ige mc","ns 566543603829","ha6 1 938 376 5","3yx 97 666 56 5","d 84 34353 2249","ah4 4209164350","rap 7729 8 125","apx 814023338 8","s 1088746413789"]
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/shj5kn39/9/
Why jsfiddle output and leetcode output of the same function are different?

Comment: A solution to *what*? What's the problem? What is supposed to happen? Is that test case failing with that result or with that input? What's the other thing (result/input)?

Answer (score 0):

You put `"s 1088746413789"` before `"apx 814023338 8"` and they reversed it.

The problem says, *The letter-logs are ordered lexicographically ignoring identifier, with the identifier used in case of ties.* Those are both letter logs.  You put them lexicographically by character, they did lexicographically by number.

That is, your order is because "1088746413789" is lexicographically before "814023338".  Their order is because 814023338 is before 1088746413789.

I think that the question was unclearly worded and should be reported as a bug.

Comment: But I don't compare ```s 1088746413789``` and ```apx 814023338 8``` because they do not satisfy the condition ```!isDigit1 && !isDigit2``` so I just return `0` in `sort` function

Comment: @AlexeyG That is even worse, you are supposed to.  Read the chunk of problem definition that I quoted - those are letter-logs and need to be ordered lexicographically.  Ordering them lexicographically requires comparisons of SOME sort.